# Kivy - adding labels for scheduled or event-driven update in python

Tags: python, label, kivy

I need to add a series of labels to my screen layout - the number of the labels are defined at runtime - and update the label texts with runtime data.
Hence, I need to add the labels programatically.

I have created a little test programme to investigate the behaviour:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random

Builder.load_string('''
<YourWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Change text"
            on_release: root.change_text()
#        Label:
#            id: label1
#            text: root.random_number
''')

class YourWidget(Widget):
    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(YourWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        label = Label(
                      id= 'label1',
                      text = root.random_number
                     )
        self.add_widget(label)
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

    def change_text(self):
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

class updatetest(App):
    def build(self):
        return YourWidget()

#if __name__ == '__main__':
if (True):
    updatetest().run()
```

If I uncomment the three lines relating to Label in the Builder.load_string, and remove the `label =` & `self.add_widget` lines from the python code, then the label gets updated as expected.

However, I have been unsuccessful in adding the label with the code as it stands.

What am I missing?

All assistance gratefully received!

Comment: Thinking about this, I wonder whether the problem is that the label is being added to 'YourWidget' and not to 'BoxLayout'.  How do I control at which point the Label is added?

Comment: Add an `id` to the `BoxLayout` and reference it in your python code as `self.ids.thatid`.

Comment: @John Anderson, that did the trick - thanks. Teaching myself Python and Kivy is an interesting experience!